# Google Play Store upload error

Tags: android, google-play

When i try to upload a signed app to the **Google Play Store** through the **Android Developer Console** i always get the error message: "Upload failed. You must add an icon to your APK file" (German original:  Hochladen fehlgeschlagen
Sie müssen ein Symbol zu Ihrer APK-Datei hinzufügen.)

So i checked my drawable folders and found following launcher icons:

- drawable-xhdpi -> ic_launcher.png 96x96
- drawable-hhdpi -> ic_launcher.png 72x72
- drawable-mhdpi -> ic_launcher.png 48x48
- drawable-lhdpi -> ic_launcher.png 36x36

And for test purposes

- drawable -> ic_launcher.png 36x36

Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    ...
```

Cleaning and rebuilding the app did not help. I even signed the app on different pc's to ensure that there is no problem with the sign process.

I am using following libs:

- ActionBarSherlock
- HoloEverywhere
- Google Play Store Lib

Unfortunately I do not know where the problem can be. 
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this problem is not associated with your apk icon. It is associated with application label defined in the string.xml file.

Please check your string.xml file for the label that you have assigned in your manifest file.

remove "/" or "\" if any in the string "app_name".

For example remove "/" or "/" in

```
<string name="app_name">example/abc</string>

<string name="app_name">exampleabc</string>"
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of you are not using your application icon.... You are using the application default widget icon ... So for test just change the icon and upload that you will not get that message.

Comment: Hi, i do not use the default icon. My icon just uses the same name as the default icon. I try to upload the app with a renamed icon. thx

Comment: Yes but its sometimes conflicted. I have also faced like this problem ..So i have suggested you rename another name and try with it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be this, described in the [Launch Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html), Point 12. Prepare promotional graphics, screenshots, and videos. There you have [Graphic and Image Assets](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en) which states:

> **High Resolution Application Icon (Required):**
>
> Use: In various locations in Google Play. The high-resolution
> application icon does not replace your launcher icon. Specs: **512x512**,
> **32-bit PNG with alpha; Max size of 1024KB**. Tip: This does not replace
> your launcher icon, but should be a higher-fidelity, higher-resolution
> version of your application's launcher icon, following the same
> guidelines. The high resolution and launcher icons should be generated
> from the same file to create a clear user experience. The recommended
> way is to start from a large size or vector graphic, and scale down
> from there. The Android Asset Studio can help create these sizes.

This might be just the part you're missing.